CustomTkinter problem in position the frame
In my Tkinter Window I tried to make 3 frames the first one done correctly and the second too but the third frame it out of the window Geometry I don't know what is the problem
(https://i.sstatic.net/zlI3H.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/3KriD.png)
def cpanel_options_frameandlabel(self):
    self.whm_options_frame = CTkFrame(
        master=self.cpanels_window_create,
        width=90,
        height=20,
        fg_color='#FF0033'
    )
    self.whm_options_frame.grid(
        row=2,
        column=00
    )
    self.cpanel_options_frame = CTkFrame(
        master=self.cpanels_window_create,
        width=250,
        height=250,
        corner_radius=1,
        border_width=0,
        fg_color='#FF0033'
    )
    self.cpanel_options_frame.grid(
        row=3,
        column=0,
        sticky='w'
    )
    self.start_options_frame = CTkFrame(
        master=self.cpanels_window_create,
        width=250,
        height=250,
        border_width=0,
        corner_radius=1,
        fg_color='#FF0033'
    )
    self.start_options_frame.grid(
        row=3,
        column=1,
        sticky='w'
    )


Most likely the frame above the top red frame has a wide width and put at column 0 as well.  You should study more on how grid works in tkinter.

the above frame in another row like,
and last two frames in the same ROW, so how can the problem be from the above frame!

The above frame and two red frames are in same column 0, so the width of column 0 will be the width of the frame because it is the wider one.  That is why the other red frame is push to right side of the window.
